# Risks and threats in signing empty SSA-89 form

Tags: united-states, risk, social-security, documents, signature

A financial institution is asking to sign form **SSA-89** which is used for verification of the **social security number** assigned a person. This verification is requested by a third party. The third party's information goes in the field company's name, company's address and company's agent (name and address) field which are empty when asked to sign.

What kind of risks/threats are involved when a person signs form SSA-89 with empty 
company's name, company's address and company's agent (name and address) field?

Is there any workaround to this?

Link to the form - https://www.ssa.gov/forms/ssa-89.pdf

Comment: is the financial institution a bank, credit Union, casino, payday lender....?

Comment: For example - Loan broker and third party is lender

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The financial institution has to explain why they need the form filled out and who will have access to the form.

By leaving those blocks blank you will give them the ability to make multiple copies and then send it to multiple companies. It will be even worse if you don't date the from that way it is good forever.

If they can't explain why and who then they might not be a trustworthy financial institution.